# Click events and MouseOut events not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, events, cross-browser, onclick, cross-platform

Not able to get into the functions for onclick & onmouseout/over  events in Chrome and Firefox. Any reasons for not working in Chrome and FF is there a way around for this. These work fine in IE9 and Opera..

Code in html page is shown below:

```
     <script language="JavaScript" for="SmartGridCell" event="onclick()">
    sg_CellClick(event.srcElement);
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" for="SmartGridCell" event="onmouseover()">
    sg_MouseOverCell(event.srcElement);
</script>
```

more click events...

```
     <script language="javascript" for="optSet" event="onclick()">
    mc_SelectAnElement(this, document.getElementsByName('optSet'));
</script>

<script language="javascript" for="answerChoice" event="onclick()">
    mc_SelectAnElement(this, document.getElementsByName('answerChoice'));
</script>
```

This is what I have done so far, but I cannot get the fire the event in Chrome...

```
 <script language="JavaScript">

  var s1=document.getElementsByName('optSet');

  for (var i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
  {
    s1[i].addEventListener("click",mc_SelectAnElement(this, document.getElementsByName('answerChoice')),false);
  }

</script>
```

Tried this as well, this snippet gets me to the function but the values selected never persists...

```
 if (document.addEventListener) 
{
    document.addEventListener("click",function (e){
    var srcElement= e.target;
    var tagName= srcElement.tagName;
    if(tagName="optSet")
    {
        mc_SelectAnElement(srcElement, document.getElementsByName('optSet'));
    }
    //mc_SelectAnElement(this, document.getElementsByName('optSet'));
    },true);
}
```

Thanks-

Comment: Oh, the weird IE. Wouldn't even *imagine* such thing to work!

Comment: yeah i would have to agree, this script is really old... I cant figure this myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern JavaScript it would be something like:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var el = e.target;
        var id = el.id;

        // the "for" attribute refers to an ID
        if (id == 'SmartGridCell' || id == 'SmartGridHeaderCell') {
            sg_CellClick(el);
        }
    }, true);

    /* repeat the same for "mouseover" and "mouseout" */
}
```

You can leave the old script too, they won't clash.

[Why this works in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) – because they invented their own ugly KnockoutJS 20 years ago. And it's non-standard of course (DOM 2 says `Reserved for future use` for the `for` and `event` attributes).

Comment: Hey, Thanks let me try this out, how could I say achieve this for OnMouseover events.

Comment: Tried the same thing that u mentioned for another click event activity, but im still facing the same issue, mentioned the old js code in the same topic under click events...

Comment: @Bluesaph, you got it right, only you should check not the `tagName` but ID of the target element. What's in the `for` attribute is an ID.

Comment: Also, pass the target element to the `mc_SelectAnElement` as the first argument (not `this`, they are not the same).

Comment: :thanks, I could get the function to work successfully thanks to the code change u mentioned but the radio button on clicking turns the submit button image(.gif) to disappear... Also the radio button click does not show on the question... Strange really...

Comment: Seems a different issue to me, please ask a separate question.